# What's the purpose of the unique index on 'value' in 'catalog_product_entity_url_key'?

Tags: magento-enterprise, database, url, enterprise-1.13, url-key

We're on a heavily modified EE 1.13.0.2 with some 20 store views - some of them sharing the same language - facing a problem with url keys.

These are generated and differ per language BUT this doesn't work reliably because of the unique index on the `value` column in `catalog_product_entity_url_key`. The unique constraint prevents duplicated url keys even if they belong to different store views.

As a result it seems impossible to have both of these links in the same magento installation:

`http://store1.example.com/product.html`
`http://store2.example.com/product.html`

Seems like in previous versions the index spanned `(store_id, value)` but was changed to `value` only. Can anyone explain why this has changed? Btw: `catalog_category_entity_url_key` doesn't have any index on its `value` column.

Is it safe to change the index back to `(store_id, value)`? Would I have to change other tables as well (e.g. tmp or index ones)?
Any other suggestion on how to work around this?

**UPDATE**
Other URL-related tables (*_url_rewrite_*) all seem to include the store_id in their unique indices so this observed abnormality is getting even weirder.

Comment: Did you ever try to change the index to (store_id, value)? I would be interested in a solution as well.

Comment: @fschmengler Index was changed to span (store_id, value) over a year ago with no apparent issues so far - well, no issues except for fixing things. just did that change after totally useless 50'000 $$$/a enterprise support kept sending me knowledge base links ... i could pm you the update script, might save you some minutes. viele gruesse nach aachen!

Comment: Danke! There's no PM feature here but you could just add it as an answer since it solved your problem. I changed the index in MySQL for testing but will need a real update script, so it would be helpful

Comment: @fschmengler the script is not a good fit for the question and was paid by a client so it won't get publicly posted. i'll try figuring out your email - which i meant by 'pm' in $this->context :)

Answer (score 2):

In general, there seem to be a few shortcomings in URL key management in EE 1.13 – read [Fabrizio Branca's blog post](http://fbrnc.net/blog/2013/04/whats-wrong-with-the-new-url-keys-in-magento).

Regarding your particular problem, it might help to change the `url_key` product attribute's scope:

```
Catalog → Attributes → Manage Attributes → Edit Attribute → Properties → Scope: Global
```

This should

- prevent having duplicate entries for the same product and
- allow the same URL Key in different store views.

Bear in mind that a **mixture** of shared and differing URL keys per product will still not be possible this way.

Comment: ty! I read Fabrizios post on my initial research, led me to asking this question. He talks about 1.13.0 where the index included the store_id which was removed until 1.13.0.2.
Changing the attribute's scope will most probably not affect the database index - wouldn't surprise me too much if it did, though :)

Comment: @pong No, it will not affect the database. It is just a "suggestion on how to work around this" you asked for.

Comment: ty again! i'm finally getting your point. should have added that we use _different_ (i.e. per language) url keys so that a global one sadly won't do.