# Magento 1.14 different websites / stores can't share a product url?

Tags: product, magento-enterprise, url-rewrite, magento-1.14

I'm in the process of an upgrade from 1.12 to 1.14 - I did an upgrade to 1.13 in between but read about a lot of issues with redirects.

I have got the site up to 1.14 without anything seemingly having issues except for the fact I still cannot get my product urls working correctly.

I have two sites, each with a product with the same name, each store needs the same slug for the product, but the domain name will change eg:

> domain.co.uk/product
>
> domain.com/product

However the second one even on a different store / website is getting '-1' added to the url, and I can't seem to clear them, as follows:

> domain.co.uk/product
>
> domain.com/product-1

I require these to be the same, but can't seem to get them to work (I've deleted a few of the Magento generated url rewrites but still bumps the user to the wrong url, which is not great for my SEO).

How do I get Magento to allow the same urls on different store levels and websites? Note, these are *two different products* on two different websites in the same installation, not the same product with different urls on different websites views. (Not the best set up I know...)

Comment: Might have to do with https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/58662/22860 as this was the case with 1.13 at least. Try to remove or change the unique index and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: I'm not so sure, see my edit.

Comment: Did you actually try removing the unique index – or expanding it to contain *store_id* as well? It's usually only on *value* so has nothing to do with same or different products. Still sounds like this is the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

The **url-key** attribute is configured to allow store specific values, It can live on a global `scope only`, `website` or `store specific`.

Try this:

1. `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > Edit Attribute > Properties > Scope` = **Global**
2. Reindex ALL

For more informations [Fabrizio Branca explanation](http://fbrnc.net/blog/2013/04/whats-wrong-with-the-new-url-keys-in-magento)